# Compare API of javascript files from java

Tags: java, javascript, comparison

I'm writing a backward compatibility automation test for a javascript library. Actually, I need to compare two javascript files of different versions and check if the API was changed. I do not need to check the implementations, only the public JS API such as method signatures, variables, constants etc.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried yet? You can simply run 'diff' from java to get the differences on two files.

Comment: What? You mean like a SVC such as Git... or even a simple `vimdiff` in your console?

Comment: So you want [JDiff](http://javadiff.sourceforge.net/), but for JavaScript sources?

Comment: I actually do not want to compare implementation of any business logic in JS, all I want to do - compare method signatures and constant names.